# Как правильно создавать объекты используя ООП на Python

Tags: python, ооп

Бьюсь над заданием уже неделю, но знаний ООП не хватает для решения. Нужно создать классы фигур треугольник, квадрат, прямоугольник и круг.
В программе имеется массив фигур, с которым можно сделать следующие операции:

1. Добавить новую фигуру
2. Посчитать периметр у всех фигур
3. Посчитать площадь у всех фигур
   Для фигуры использовать базовый абстрактный класс фигуры, у которого есть методы посчитать периметр и посчитать площадь фигуры.
   Массив фигур в программе должен быть представлен как массив объектов этого базового класса.
   Массив фигур должен создаваться и вся работа с ним идёт внутри main.
   При создании фигур необходимо осуществлять проверку входных данных на возможность создания данной фигуры и в случае ошибки выдавать соответствующие сообщения.
   Вот что мне удалось сделать, но работу завернули:

```
import abc
import math
 
 
class Figure(metaclass=abc.ABCMeta):
 
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def perimeter(self):
        pass
 
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def area(self):
        pass
 
 
class Triangle(Figure):
    def __init__(self, side_a, side_b, side_c):
        self.side_a = side_a
        self.side_b = side_b
        self.side_c = side_c
 
        if type(self.side_a) in (int, float) and type(self.side_b) in (int, float) and \
                type(self.side_c) in (int, float):
            pass
        else:
            raise ValueError(f"Wrong data type for {self.__class__.__name__}!")
 
    def perimeter(self):
        return self.side_a + self.side_b + self.side_c
 
    def area(self):
        p = (self.side_a + self.side_b + self.side_c) / 2
        return math.sqrt(p * (p - self.side_a) * (p - self.side_b) * (p - self.side_c))
 
    def calculator(self):
        print(f"______{self.__class__.__name__}______")
        return f"Perimeter is: {round(self.perimeter(), 3)}\nArea is: {round(self.area(), 3)}"
 
 
class Square(Figure):
    def __init__(self, side_a):
        self.side_a = side_a
 
        if type(self.side_a) in (int, float):
            pass
        else:
            raise ValueError(f"Wrong data type for {self.__class__.__name__}!")
 
    def perimeter(self):
        return 4 * self.side_a
 
    def area(self):
        return self.side_a * self.side_a
 
    def calculator(self):
        print(f"______{self.__class__.__name__}______")
        return f"Perimeter is: {round(self.perimeter(), 3)}\nArea is: {round(self.area(), 3)}"
 
 
class Rectangle(Figure):
    def __init__(self, side_a, side_b):
        self.side_a = side_a
        self.side_b = side_b
 
        if type(self.side_a) in (int, float) and type(self.side_b) in (int, float):
            pass
        else:
            raise ValueError(f"Wrong data type for {self.__class__.__name__}!")
 
    def perimeter(self):
        return 2 * (self.side_a + self.side_b)
 
    def area(self):
        return self.side_a * self.side_b
 
    def calculator(self):
        print(f"______{self.__class__.__name__}______")
        return f"Perimeter is: {round(self.perimeter(), 3)}\nArea is: {round(self.area(), 3)}"
 
 
class Circle(Figure):
    def __init__(self, radius):
        self.radius = radius
 
        if type(self.radius) in (int, float):
            pass
        else:
            raise ValueError(f"Wrong data type for {self.__class__.__name__}!")
 
    def perimeter(self):
        return 2 * math.pi * self.radius
 
    def area(self):
        return math.pi * self.radius * self.radius
 
    def calculator(self):
        print(f"______{self.__class__.__name__}______")
        return f"Perimeter is: {round(self.perimeter(), 3)}\nArea is: {round(self.area(), 3)}"
 
 
if __name__ == '__main__':
 
    figures = []
 
    circle = Circle(1.5)
    figures.append(circle)
 
    rectangle = Rectangle(10, 5)
    figures.append(rectangle)
 
    square = Square(10)
    figures.append(square)
 
    triangle = Triangle(2, 2, 3)
    figures.append(triangle)
 
    triangle2 = Triangle(1, 2, 3)
    figures.append(triangle2)
 
    for i in figures:
        print(i.calculator())
```

Причина отказа была следующая:

1. В математике квадрат - это прямоугольник.
2. Круг не имеет периметер, а имеет длинну окружности.
3. Можно выделить более аккуратно иерархию классов, а так же использовать принципы SOLID.

Помогите, пожалуйста! Как это правильно реализовать? Как здесь должно идти правильное наследование? И как мне при данных условиях конкретно у круга вызывать метод подсчета длины окружности вместо периметра?

Answer (score 2):

См. комментарии в коде - по замечаниям и вообще.
Не уверен насчет строгой академичности подходов и соблюдения SOLID :)

```
import abc
import math


class Figure(metaclass=abc.ABCMeta):

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def area(self):
        pass

    # Периметр — длина контура замкнутой плоской фигуры, длина границы (Википедия)
    # Периметр, оказывается, общее понятие и для прямолинейных и криволинейных фигур
    # В том числе периметр - это длина окружности (синоним "периметр окружности")
    # поэтому метод perimeter() переосмыслен - он будет возвращать кортеж (название контура, значение)
    # если периметр как обобщающее понятие для длины контура (границы) фигуры категорически не подходит,
    # можно переименовать этот метод, например, в "contour_length()"
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def perimeter(self):  
        pass

    # метод calculator() - общий для всех с идентичной реализацией
    def calculator(self):
        print(f"______{self.__class__.__name__}______")
        result = self.perimeter() # получаем кортеж с названием контура и значением
        return f"{result[0]} is: {round(result[1], 3)}\nArea is: {round(self.area(), 3)}"

    def check_args(self, *args):  # универсальный метод для проверки параметров (не дублировать в наследниках)
    # сюда же можно добавить проверку аргументов на неотрицательность (опция)
        for v in args:
            if type(v) not in (int, float):
                raise ValueError(f"Wrong data type for {self.__class__.__name__}!")


class Triangle(Figure):
    def __init__(self, side_a, side_b, side_c):
        self.sides = (side_a, side_b, side_c)  # сделал покомпактнее хранение параметров фигур
        self.check_args(*self.sides)

    def area(self):
        p = sum(self.sides) / 2
        return math.prod([p] + [p - s for s in self.sides])  # тоже покороче - произведение элементов списка

    def perimeter(self):
        return "Perimeter", sum(self.sides)  # возвращает кортеж с названием контура и значением


class Rectangle(Figure):
    def __init__(self, side_a, side_b):
        self.sides = (side_a, side_b)
        self.check_args(*self.sides)

    def area(self):
        return math.prod(self.sides)

    def perimeter(self):
        return "Perimeter", 2 * sum(self.sides)


class Square(Rectangle):  # В математике квадрат - это прямоугольник (наследуем квадрат от прямоугольника)
    def __init__(self, side_a, side_b=None):
        if side_b is None:
            side_b = side_a
        self.check_args(side_a, side_b)  # проверяем типы перед нахождением минимума, чтобы не возникла ошибка сравнения
        side = min(side_a, side_b)
        super().__init__(side, side)


class Circle(Figure):
    def __init__(self, radius):
        self.radius = radius
        self.check_args(self.radius)

    def area(self):
        return math.pi * self.radius ** 2

    def perimeter(self):
        return "Circumference", 2 * math.pi * self.radius  # Круг имеет не периметер, а длину окружности


if __name__ == '__main__':

    figures = [Circle(1.5), Square(10), Triangle(2, 2, 3), Triangle(1, 2, 3)]

    for i in figures:
        print(i.calculator())
```

```
______Circle______
Circumference is: 9.425
Area is: 7.069
______Square______
Perimeter is: 40
Area is: 100
______Triangle______
Perimeter is: 7
Area is: 3.938
______Triangle______
Perimeter is: 6
Area is: 0.0
```

Comment: Посмотрел - все очень логично и красиво выглядит! Посмотрим что на это скажет наш строгий преподаватель) Спасибо вам большое за помощь!

Comment: Немного переосмыслил концепт, стало еще компактнее - см. примечания

Comment: Поменяли интерфейс для квадрата, нарушив LSP. Можно добавить возможность указать 2 стороны. Указывать вторую сторону можно опционально. и добавить проверку, что они равны.

Comment: @Alpensin спасибо, дельное замечание. Поправил